# Social Media Announcement

Tags: word, knowledge, visual

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #16: Restricted Title: xkcd 2000-2500](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/monthly-topic-challenge-16-restricted-title-xkcd-2000-2500).</sub>

---

**Inspired by [xkcd 2045](https://xkcd.com/2045), I made my own social media moves:**

[image: announcement]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks! Same to you!

> I+WHATSAPP−WAITS = HAPP

> YouTube's capital letters = YT

> SNAPCHAT+AI−CAPTAINS = HA

> LINKEDIN−ID−LINE = NK

> INSTAGRAM−MARTIAN = SG

> I (moved to…)

> 40% of VIBER = VI

> MESSENGER−ER−SEEMS = NG

> All in all, HAPPY THANKSGIVING.

Comment: Oof, you pipped me by a handful of seconds! Well done, super speedy :)